# Typescript keyof generic condition

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to make the **type** property depend on the value of **name**? I tired this, but it doesn't work:

```
type Attribute<T> = {
  name: keyof T;
  type: T[keyof T] extends string ? 'a' : 'b';
};

type Item = {
  id: string;
  date: number;
};

const att1: Attribute<Item> = {
  name: 'id',
  type: 'a', // this should work
};

const att2: Attribute<Item> = {
  name: 'id',
  type: 'b', // this should not work
};

const att3: Attribute<Item> = {
  name: 'date',
  type: 'b', // this should work
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `T[keyof T] extends string` is expanded to all types that `T[keyof T]` can assume, and at least one of them doesn't extend `string`, so the condition is always `false`.

One solution is to use a mapped type to produce an object type whose values are all the allowed types, then index that with `keyof T` again to get a union of the individual types out:

```
type Attribute<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: {
    name: K,
    type: T[K] extends string ? 'a' : 'b';
  }
}[keyof T]
```

I'm not sure this is the simplest solution, but it [does seem to work](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAgswCcCWAjArsCAeAKgPigF4oBvAKCigG0BpKJAOygGsIQB7AMyhwF0AuUhUpQGAQwC2EQTQA0wyqEiCctXlAgAPTAwAmAZyj7EjAOZQA-FADkY61EHWU1gNzCAvmXdVWHbnzIyJWgASUwJIiFKJF1BY2QGUzdKXTFMQQY0CRQIBDd3NzIAY3YGYyg04ABGQTgTdEwsMIgJAmJySnEpRxjreUVwaRs7WSgAejGoYAALJEN9afY0ABtdKAB3dgRmL0KSsuAK+AAmWvhkBuxm1siO0Ukh617+qcHHZ1GJqdn5xZW1hjsQ6bba7QL7cqVADMZ3qGCu4TaUXu3RsqUwfWEwUcI3GkxmcyMf1WoiBGy2OwK4NKkPgABZYRd4U1EbdhF1HuiIJiBsobB88d9CQsliSQZSXEA).

Comment: Thank you Thomas, this was very educational!